$L'=\left \{ z^Rx : xyz\in L \right \}$ is regular
Let $L$ be a regular language over $\Sigma = \left \{ 0,1 \right \}$.
The question asked to show that $L'=\left \{ z^Rx : xyz\in L \right \}$ where $x,y,z\in \Sigma^*$ is regular.
What I tried
$L$ is regular, thus $L=L(A) : A=\left \{ \Sigma,Q,q_0,\left \{ q_f \right \} ,\delta\right \}$
(I'm assuming w.l.o.g that $A$ has a single accepting state)
For each $p,q\in Q$, let $A_{p,q}$ be the automaton $A$, except that initial state is $p$ and final state is $q$.
Let $h$ be the following substitution:
$h : \Sigma\to P(\Sigma^*) \ s.t\ \; \forall \sigma\in\Sigma\ , \ h(\sigma)=\left \{ \varepsilon \right \}$
From the closer porpitas of regular languages we get that
$$L'=\bigcup_{q,p\in Q}\left (L(A_{q_0,q})\cdot h(L(A_{q,p}))\cdot (L(A_{p,q_f})^R \right )^R$$
is a regular language.
I can't decide if this attempt is correct.

We discourage "Is my attempted solution correct?" questions, as answers are unlikely to help future readers.  Part of our mission is to build a repository of knowledge that will be helpful to others in the future.

Let $A = (\Sigma, Q, q_0, \delta, F)$ be a DFA that recognizes $L$. For states $p, q\in Q$, let $A_{p, q}$ denote the DFA obtained from $A$ by letting $p$ be the initial state and $q$ be the only accepting state. Thus, $A_{p, q} = (\Sigma, Q, p, \delta, \{ q\})$. So  the DFA $A_{p, q}$ accepts only all words $x$ such that $p\xrightarrow{x}q$ is a run in $A$.  Let $h:\Sigma^* \to \Sigma^*$ be the homomorphism that maps the empty word, and every letter to the empty word. In particular, $h(w) = \epsilon$ for all $w\in \Sigma^*$.
To understand how to describe $L'$ in terms of other regular languages of the form $A_{p, q}$, we consider its definition. It is not hard to see that and input $w$ is in $L'$ only when there are words $x, y$ and $z$ such that:

$A$ accepts $xyz$, and
$w = z^{rev}x$.

Condition 1. can be specified as follows: there are states $p_1, p_2\in Q$ and $q_f\in F$ such that $q_0 \xrightarrow{x}p_1 \xrightarrow{y} p_2 \xrightarrow{z} q_f$. That is, $x\in A_{q_0, p_1}, y\in A_{p_1, p_2}$, and $z \in A_{p_2, q_f}$. Then, condition 2. suggests that $w^{rev} = x^{rev} z$.
As "there exists" can be specified by union of languages, then by combining the  latter facts, we get that $$(L')^{rev} = \bigcup\limits_{p_1, p_2\in Q, q_f\in F:  \ L(A_{p_1, p_2}) \neq \emptyset} \left[L(A_{q_0, p_1})^{rev}  \cdot L(A_{p_2, q_f}) \right]$$
Therefore,
$$L' = \left[\bigcup\limits_{p_1, p_2\in Q, q_f\in F:  \ L(A_{p_1, p_2}) \neq \emptyset} \left[ L(A_{q_0, p_1})^{rev}  \cdot L(A_{p_2, q_f}) \right]\right]^{rev}$$
As regular languages are closed under finite union, concatenation, and reverse, we are done.
Note that I handled the fact that $p_2$ is reachable from $p_1$ in $A$ by putting a condition on the union. What you essentially did is writing  the following expression (BTW, I take union also across accepting state $q_f$'s as a DFA has a set of accepting states):
$$(L')^{rev} = \bigcup\limits_{p_1, p_2\in Q, q_f\in F} \left[L(A_{q_0, p_1})^{rev}  \cdot h(L(A_{p_1, p_2})) \cdot L(A_{p_2, q_f}) \right]$$
The above expression is also fine as $h(K) = \{ \epsilon\}$ for any nonempty language $K$, and $h(\emptyset) = \emptyset$. Therefore, when $p_2$ is not reachable from $p_1$, we get that $L(A_{p_1, p_2}) = \emptyset$, and so $L(A_{q_0, p_1})^{rev}  \cdot h(L(A_{p_1, p_2})) \cdot L(A_{p_2, q_f}) $ does not contribute to the union in this case. Yet, I prefer the former expression as it explicitly states the condition on $p_2$ and $p_1$, and thus is slightly easier to prove.
Now by reversing both sides, we get that
$$L' = \left[\bigcup\limits_{p_1, p_2\in Q, q_f\in F} \left[L(A_{q_0, p_1})^{rev}  \cdot h(L(A_{p_1, p_2})) \cdot L(A_{p_2, q_f}) \right]\right]^{rev}$$
$$ = \bigcup\limits_{p_1, p_2\in Q, q_f\in F} \left[L(A_{q_0, p_1})^{rev}  \cdot h(L(A_{p_1, p_2})) \cdot L(A_{p_2, q_f}) \right]^{rev}$$
You can see your mistake already here. You got the reverse on the wrong language in the inner expression.
Anyway, we can simplify the expression even further:
$$ = \bigcup\limits_{p_1, p_2\in Q, q_f\in F}  L(A_{p_2, q_f})^{rev}\cdot h(L(A_{p_1, p_2}))^{rev} \cdot  L(A_{q_0, p_1})  $$
and as $\emptyset^{rev} = \emptyset$ and $\{ \epsilon^{rev}\} = \{ \epsilon\}$, we get that the above expression is simplified to:
$$ = \bigcup\limits_{p_1, p_2\in Q, q_f\in F}  L(A_{p_2, q_f})^{rev}\cdot h(L(A_{p_1, p_2})) \cdot  L(A_{q_0, p_1})  $$
The end result reads nicely: we have a reverse on a word $z$ that leads to $q_f$ from $p_2$, followed by a condition that $p_2$ is reachable from $p_1$, and finally ending with a word $x$ that leads to $p_1$ from $q_0$.
So you confused the language you should reverse, and it seems that you assume that $A$ has a single accepting state. Other than that, the idea you followed looks fine. Also, using the homomorphism $h$ is okay, but it might be less obvious that it implements the condition of $p_2$ being reachable from $p_1$.

Hello and thank you for the answer.
There are three points in your answer I want to be sure that I understood.
The first one discusses about the reachability.
What I understood from your answer is that the problem with what I wrote is if $p_2$ is not reachable from $p_1$ then $L(A_{p_1,p_2})=\emptyset$ , thus the all expression goes to $\emptyset$.

The second point is also about reachability.
Why you can't apply the same reasoning for $L(A_{p_2,q_f})$ ?
what guarantees that $q_f$ is reachable from $q_2$ ?

The third and the last point is about the order of the concatenation in the expression I wrote.
I will explain using the following illustration:
$$q_0\overset{x}{\rightarrow}q\overset{y}{\rightarrow}p\overset{z}{\rightarrow}q_f$$
The expatriation I wrote gives you:
$$(x\cdot \varepsilon \cdot z^R)^R =(xz^R)^R=z^Rx$$
which is what the question demands (assuming of course there is a path from $q$ to $p$ and $R$ is the reverse operator)

@Daniel I missed the fact that $h(\emptyset) = \emptyset$. I edited my answer.

Is it possible to continue the chat here ?https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/154838/lzrxxyzl-is-regular

@Daniel yes, you can post there if anything is still unclear.
